# Any way to keep an html button pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button `<input type="button" name="name" value="value"/>`. 
Is there any way to keep it visually pressed and unpress it via javascript?

Thanks

Comment: @Oded: I'd imagine he'd like to use it as a toggle button. I suppose it'd be possible with radio buttons but that would be a lot of faff.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. I have a library from which I'm building a UI, however the buttons are not like the jQuery toggle buttons (which are the ones I need). I don't know how can I go around to intertwine the two libraries (the one I'm using and jQuery UI). Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would try CSS and use the border-style `inset`, personally.

```
<input type="button" value="Inset Border" style="border-style:inset;" />
```

For a list of different styles, please see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/4mUsP/1/).

Comment: Me too thought of CSS trick but I think he is talking about on/off button represented by pressed/unpressed button. @ThiefMaster's suggestion will better suit the need.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: Applying a class on click isn't feasible? It only has to _appear_ pressed, doesn't actually have to be. ;-)

Comment: This works perfectly with JavaScript: "pressedButton.style.borderStyle = "inset".  Here's a list of properties you can set in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference

Comment: Setting the border-style to inset alone didn't give me the visual effect I was hoping for. Adding "background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#f0f0f0,#dfdfdf);" with inset did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

No, that's not possible.

I'd suggest you to use something like the [jQuery UI Buttons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/). They support exactly this behaviour: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do that with javascript.

But you can use javascript to simulate that effect by adding/removing a css class, or directly editing the css properties you have chosen to use.

Answer (score 4):

toggle the visual state of the button by:

```
btn.onclick=function(e) {
    this.style.borderStyle = (this.style.borderStyle!=='inset' ? 'inset' : 'outset'); 
}
```

when you need to see if it's depressed simply check if `btn.style.borderStyle==='inset'`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function pp() {
    if(document.getElementById('pBut').innerHTML == 'Pause'){
        // do some stuff
        document.getElementById('pBut').innerHTML = 'Continue';
        document.getElementById('pBut').style.borderStyle = 'inset';
    }
    else {
        // do some other stuff
        document.getElementById('pBut').innerHTML = 'Pause';
        document.getElementById('pBut').style.borderStyle = 'outset';
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="pBut" type="button" onclick="pp()" title="Pause or continue the chapter.">Pause</button>
```

Works for me. Tested With FireFox and Opera, but should be compatible with all browsers.

Comment: Thank you @nonzaprej, for your edit. It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `document.getElementById("some_id").style.border.`

```
<input id="some_id" onTap="change_me()" type="button" name="name" value="value"/>

var button_switch = "on";
function change_me(){
    if(button_switch==="on"){
        document.getElementById("some_id").style.border = "3px inset rgb(254, 255, 208)";
        button_switch = "off";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("some_id").style.border = "3px outset rgb(254, 255, 208)";
        button_switch = "on";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from Brad Christie's answer, a slightly modified example based on an anchor HTML element, which improves the visual aspect by setting a different background and rounded corners:

```
<a class="bouton" style="border-width:1px;border-radius:3px;" onclick="javascript:this.style.borderStyle = (this.style.borderStyle!==\'inset\' ? \'inset\' : \'outset\');this.style.background = (this.style.borderStyle!==\'inset\' ? \'\' : \'#ccc\')" value="Details" >&hellip;</a>
```

The CSS description of the button:

```
a.bouton {
display:inline-block;
width:40px;
height:18px;
background-image:url('bouton_gris_petit.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border: 1px solid #888;
font-size:11.3px;
color:#666;
cursor:pointer;
text-shadow:#666 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
border-radius:3px;
}
```

To download the picture of the button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1xVV.png