# How to automatically click a division using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created some buttons using jquery and when I click them some event occurs, I want one of the button remain in clicked state initially so that I can see same effect initially as I see after when I click the same button.
As for example I have created a button using a division named as "btn" then I would like to know what code in jquery will keep in clicked state.

Comment: Are you talking about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238314/any-way-to-keep-an-html-button-pressed I am not sure to understand

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you actually asking how to detect a click event?

Comment: do you need a toggle button? btw the question is not very clear

Comment: you need to `.trigger('name')`

Comment: Do you mean actual `<button> / <input>` tags; or are these `<div> / <a>` tags which you've applied CSS to?

Comment: There is no <a> attribute it is just a division I used as a button. @MattSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on `document ready`:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn").trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#target" ).click();
});
```

Comment: I am not sure he is talking about this. I think hewants to know how to keep the button in a pressed state.

Comment: I think, he want button pressed on initital state(ie when page load)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#btn').click();
    },0);

});
```